# How to make sense of phonon dispersion curves and dynamic stability?

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons, density-functional-theory

I've been working on this material that I've been doing DFT calculations on and I've managed to obtain the phonon dispersion curves for it. Calculation for it took quite a while, but here it is:
[image]

Now my question is, how does the phonon dispersion curve relate to dynamic stability of this particular lattice? So I know that the negative frequencies imply dynamic instability and, thus, the transient nature of the structure, but why are negative frequencies calculated in the first place? What other general inferences can one derive from the plot that I've shown? Thanks for helping out, everyone.

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1635/671 https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3657/671

Comment: Thank you so much for this!